# How can you get any version of Linux to see the 2018 MacBook Pro SSD?

Tags: linux, macintosh, ssd

I have tried 
    `nvme_load=yes`
in place of 
    `quiet ---`
with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and Xubuntu 18.04.
`df -h` results in only the system generated mounts and the installation media.
The weekly live including firmware image of Debian also fails to discover the ssd.

I have located more information on the SSD. I found this information in the system profiler on OS X High Sierra.

```
Apple SSD Controller:
APPLE SSD AP1024M:
Capacity:   1 TB (1,000,555,581,440 bytes)
TRIM Support:   Yes
Model:  APPLE SSD AP1024M
Revision:   177.77.7
Serial Number:  C02829600M9JPD216
Link Width: x4
Link Speed: 8.0 GT/s
Detachable Drive:   No
BSD Name:   disk0
Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table) . 
Removable Media:    No
S.M.A.R.T. status:  Verified
```

`lsblk` from a xubuntu 18.04.1 live installer does not show any pcie or nvme devices.

Note: the installer and Gparted fail to list it. Typically these both require an unmounted drive to work with. So, it simply does not see the SSD. I read that this system uses a PCIE SSD , though im not sure how to send a kernel module to allow use of it.

Comment: Do the fail to discover it, or do they just fail to mount it?

Comment: Well, the installer and Gparted fail to list it. Typically these both require an unmounted drive to work with. So, it simply does not see the SSD. I read that this system uses a PCIE SSD , though im not sure how to send a kernel module to allow use of it.

Comment: It is fairly know the latest Mac models are not compatible yet.

Comment: This question is in a French newspaper: https://www.nextinpact.com/brief/sur-les-mac-recents--la-puce-t2-bloque-l-installation-de-linux-6383.htm

Answer (score 21):

It's currently not possible to install anything except Windows 10 on Apple computers [equipped with T2 chip](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862). This security chip makes it impossible to see the internal drive, Apple generously did an exception only for Windows 10 (but only if you install it via Boot Camp). 
A possible option could be Linux installed on a USB/Thunderbolt external drive, unfortunately I tried this only for Windows but it worked (though the internal drive was not visible).

Update: changing the [Secure Boot](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330) option makes no difference.

**Update 2** (July 2019): custom patching of linux kernel seems to [do the thing](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/71#issuecomment-507325112), unfortunately it's a pretty nerdy solution.

[Source](https://www.crystalidea.com/blog/fan-control-on-apple-computers-with-t2-chip-on-windows-boot-camp)

Comment: Wow. Why the heck does turning off secure boot not fix the problem?! Apple says on their own site: "The 'No Security' setting doesn't enforce any of the above security requirements for your startup disk." Wat?!

Comment: I don't know, but it's sadly true.

Comment: This is precisely the outcome that Linux users were decrying a few years back when Microsoft was starting to require secure boot. And now, Microsoft has done the right thing, but Apple is the one creating the exact dystopia that was predicted. How are they getting a pass on this?

Comment: Well, [someone posted a patch](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MacBook-Finally-Linux-SSD-RW) that allows to see the SSD. The news article in turn refers to a big thread on github. You may want to update your answer on that.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, updated.

Answer (score 14):

I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2018 and managed to get the SSD working for like 10 seconds.

When you live boot Linux Mint or Ubuntu and do:

```
modprobe nvme
```

Then check for the hardware ID of the Apple Storage controller by doing:

```
lspci -nn | grep NVMe
```

Then put that ID in the new_id file under nvme:

```
echo 106b 2005 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id
```

When you did that it shows up under `lsblk` but only for like 10~30 seconds before the machine randomly turns off after 1second of full cooler spin 100%. I am not sure why this happens, but it does seem to detect it correctly as for me it showed a 500GB NVMe ssd under `lsblk`. I didn't manage to get `gparted` opened as it took longer than the time before it shuts off.

Comment: I'd be careful assuming this actually defeated the lock.  Depending on how the T2 works it could be waiting for access then detecting an unauthorized access attempt and shutting down the system for protection.

Comment: Please update your post if you had any more luck getting this to work.

Comment: @TomB still no solution to this issue :( I will post an update whenever I do have findings.

Answer (score -1):

Try Manjaro Linux 19. Its kernel has the necessary drivers for the SSD. It can even recognize the touchpad and the keyboard. Don't forget to tell me if it works.

Comment: Nope, only custom kernel is able to see internal NVMe storage.